# How to update knockout binding with jQuery?

Tags: knockout.js

In the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lqsx/2088/

I've bound the second button to a function that reverses the direction of the counter.

If I click the button, the new binding doesn't apply until after I click the first button once.  It should take effect immediately.

How to I force this new binding to take effect immediately?

Code:

```
var ClickCounterViewModel = function() {
this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(0);

this.registerClick = function() {
    this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() + 1);
};

this.changeClickBinding = function() {
     $('#clicker').attr('data-bind', 'click: function(){numberOfClicks(numberOfClicks() - 1)}');
};

this.resetClicks = function() {
    this.numberOfClicks(0);
};

this.hasClickedTooManyTimes = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.numberOfClicks() >= 3;
}, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ClickCounterViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's not a good idea to try to dynamically change your bindings after you call `applyBindings`. That function is what Knockout uses to evaluate the code in your `data-bind` attributes. If you change them after, the behavior you'll get isn't defined (as far as I can tell).

In addition, you're mixing jQuery and Knockout for DOM updates and event handling, which can lead to confusing code later on. Knockout can handle all this for you:

```
var ClickCounterViewModel = function() {
  this.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(0);
  this.clickDirection = ko.observable(1);

  this.registerClick = function() {
    this.numberOfClicks(this.numberOfClicks() + this.clickDirection());
  };

  this.changeClickBinding = function() {
    this.clickDirection(this.clickDirection() * -1)
  };

  this.resetClicks = function() {
    this.numberOfClicks(0);
  };

  this.hasClickedTooManyTimes = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.numberOfClicks() >= 3;
  }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ClickCounterViewModel());
```

I added a new observable, `clickDirection`, to control whether the counter is incrementing or decrementing. The `changeClickBinding` function now just flips that number.

Comment: I need to do it via jQuery because I have an MVC view with Razor-generated attributes.  I know it can/should be done with knockout, but in this particular situation I don't think that's an option.  Here's a question with this detailed more:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946638/dom-not-updating-correctly-when-altering-knockout-bindings-with-jquery

Comment: I can understand why you want to do that, but your problem is still that you're trying to mash Knockout, jQuery, and server-side templating together in a way that makes it difficult to use Knockout. Which leads you to trying to update bindings with jQuery, which KO can't handle well. The company where I work faced a similar issue and has moved towards writing all the data into a JSON object on the page and binding everything with KO.

Comment: I can't do that because the initial page and its contents need to be viewable by non-JS users and crawlable by search engines :/  I'm surprised there isn't a way to "re-apply" the ko bindings in this new element

Comment: You can try calling cleanNode and then applyBindings again, but that hasn't always worked for me.

Comment: Generate a "static" initial page (what a search engine or JS-blocked user would see) on the server side and have your JS code initially remove the server-generated elements and then use KO to generate their initial replacement the way JeffB said.